# What is this very small bug with brown and tan spots?

Tags: bugs, bug-identification

Around my house I've been spotting these very small brown/tan spotted bugs:

[image: bug]

It moves quite slow, and doesn't seem to fly, only crawl (though it does look like it has wings).  It's very small, not much bigger than a sugar ant for comparison.

What is this bug?  This is in the Philadelphia region of Pennsylvania.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is almost certainly one of the [Dermestidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dermestidae), known as skin bugs or carpet beetles. I think this is probably a [varied carpet beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varied_carpet_beetle) (*Anthrenus verbasci*)  They are a common world-wide pest and the larvae are known to eat a range of mostly animal-derived materials containing keratin or chitins, including things like wool, silk, leather, bone, horn and feathers.

As per comment from @Willeke that this is a common question:

*They don't pose a risk to us, but can cause damage to carpets, clothes, books, food stuffs and similar items.* If your carpets or blankets are made from wool or other animal product, these are the most common  items to be damaged.

The larvae look a lot like a very small hairy caterpillar (photo by André Karwath aka Aka, CC BY-SA 2.5 https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5, via Wikimedia Commons):

[image: Anthrenus verbasci larvae]

and the adults (photo by Donald Hobern from Copenhagen, Denmark, CC BY 2.0 https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0, via Wikimedia Commons:

[image: Anthrenus verbasci adult]

Comment: I think its a varied carpet beetle looking at the images.